# template class for nullables on primitive types

Tags: c#

I would like to achieve the following:

```
int? a = 1;
int? b = 2;
int? smallerInt = NullableOps<int>.Min(a, b);

float? c = 1;
float? d = 2;
float? smallerFloat = NullableOps<float>.Min(a, b);
```

Currently the `NullableOps` is:

```
public class NullableOps<T>
{
    public static Nullable<T> Min(Nullable<T> a, Nullable<T> b)
    {
        // do some stuff
        var x = a.Value < b.Value ? a : b; // error here: '<' can't be applied to operand T and T
    }
}
```

But it's got errors like `T must not be a nullable type`.
So I have to duplicate the same code for different types using function overloading:

```
public class NullableOps
{
    public static int? Min(int? a, int? b)
    {
        // do stuff
    }

    public static float? Min(float? a, float? b)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

But I don't wanna do that because every time when I add a new type, I need to duplicate the code again. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add following constraint.

```
public class NullableOps<T> where T : struct
```

The error describes that the compiler has no guarantee that Parameter Type `T` won't be non-nullable.

When you use `Nullable<T>`, the type parameter `T` must be a non-nullable value type, for example `int,float`. (It cannot be `int?`). You can enforce this by using the constrain that `T` is a value type (struct)

**Update : Based on Edit**

Based on on the update in OP, you need to add `IComparable<T>` constraint and use `CompareTo` instead of "<". For example,

```
public class NullableOps<T> where T : struct,IComparable<T>
{
    public static Nullable<T> Min(Nullable<T> a, Nullable<T> b)
    {
         return a.Value.CompareTo(b.Value) < 0 ? a : b; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Would be helpful if you explain why

Comment: @devNull Have added a brief description. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your code & explanation. I have just now edited my code where there is an error: `the operator < can't be applied to operand of T`. Can you help me with this too?